# How can I find my Facebook app id and secret key?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have already registered as a Facebook Developer but i am not finding any app id and secret key . Can Anyone help me ??

Answer (score 1):

The list of all your apps and their settings (including id and secret) is here:

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps

You may want to check out some tutorials about facebook apps, for example:

> http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/09/20/developing-a-facebook-application-for-absolute-beginners/

Also, the official documentation is not that bad, but pretty big:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: Can You Be More Specefic..??

Comment: this is where you have to create an app. you have to create an app first to get app id and secret (they are unique for every app).

Comment: yap....I tried ..they says You have to create Test user....when I tried To Configure test user..I need app id and Secret key...that's problem i have Been Facing...??

Comment: usually you don´t need test users (never used them in any projects). it may help if you include a screenshot in your question. normally there is a button for creating a new app at the top right corner of the page, and you just need to fill in a captcha and put in a name for the app. after that you got it in the list, and in the right column you see the app id and the secret.

Comment: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/09/20/developing-a-facebook-application-for-absolute-beginners/
this is outdated....there is No captcha in Creating the Apps.....you Can Try ..

Comment: yeah, i just took the first tutorial. there are plenty out there, earlier there was no captcha, now you get it for every new app. the developer settings are changing the whole time though, but the default setup should be fine for the beginning.

Comment: so have you been able to create an app now?

Comment: @luschn: maybe you could just give him teh codez?

Comment: may i ask why the downvote? please explain so i can improved my answer if something is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a developer link at the bottom of the page, after opening it you will find apps link at top right of page, click it to see your apps detail.

or

simple way is just login to facebook and copy below link to your browser.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: if this post is helpful to you don't forget to tick it answer.

Comment: dear when you create your app, app id and secret key automatically generated.